# Sort posts by most viewed Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting, post, output

I searched the site and didn't find what I was looking for. I have a functioning code, only the output is wrong, and that's why I think it is not working.

Here is my code so far:

This is in functions:

```
function getPostViews($postID){
    $count_key = 'post_views_count';
    $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
    if($count==''){
        delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
        add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
        return '0 View';
    }
    return $count.' Views';
}

// function to count views.
function setPostViews($postID) {
    $count_key = 'post_views_count';
    $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
    if($count==''){
        $count = 0;
        delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
        add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
    }else{
        $count++;
        update_post_meta($postID, $count_key, $count);
    }
}

// Add it to a column in WP-Admin - (Optional)
add_filter('manage_posts_columns', 'posts_column_views');
add_action('manage_posts_custom_column', 'posts_custom_column_views',5,2);
function posts_column_views($defaults){
    $defaults['post_views'] = __('Views');
    return $defaults;
}
function posts_custom_column_views($column_name, $id){
    if($column_name === 'post_views'){
        echo getPostViews(get_the_ID());
    }
}

$args = array(  'numberposts'  => 4,  /* get 4 posts, or set -1 for all */
                'orderby'      => 'meta_value_num',  /* this will look at the meta_key you set below */
                'meta_key'     => 'post_views_count',
                'order'        => 'DESC',
                'post_type'    => 'post',
                'post_status'  => 'publish'
            );
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach( $myposts as $mypost ) {
    $id = $mypost->ID;
            $post_views = intval($post->views);
            $post_title = get_the_title($post);
            $post_title = $post->post_title;

}
```

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Hello and thank youa lot for the quick response. The error I am having is that the posts do not sort by most viewed, but are sorted by default WP. I will include screenshots as soon as possible.

Comment: http://imageshack.com/a/img196/2782/xyhk.png This is an example of what I wish to acheive. When I click on the post "Development Team" a lot of times when logged off the website, I can not see it can be sorted as the post with most views.

Answer (score 0):

try changing `'orderby' => 'meta_value_num'` to `'orderby' => 'meta_value meta_value_num'` or `'orderby' => 'meta_value_num meta_value'`. I've seen this solution work for some people.

I've actually had a very similar issue to this. Try dumping the SQL (tutorial here: http://ben.lobaugh.net/blog/45390/wordpress-how-to-view-the-sql-query-generated-by-wp_query) and see what it looks like. I found the SQL was wrong when I was having this issue.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have treid this but it will still not sort itself by most viewed.

Comment: @user1805959 Can you dump the SQL WP_Query generates here?